# Compile with openssl-1.0.1e but linked against old glibc

Tags: linux, openssl, glibc

Desirable result:

compile a binary with statically linked openssl 1.0.1e but dynamically linked glibc, stdc++, etc. Binary should run on most servers, for example Ubuntu 11.04 or RHEL 6, CentOS 6.4.

Problem:

code I want to compile depends on openssl 1.0.1e. Openssl 1.0.1e depends on glibc found in newer versions of Ubuntu (like 12.04, glibc 2.13) and doesn't compile against the one found in Ubuntu 11.04.

The binary compiled on Ubuntu 12.04 fails to run on Ubuntu 11.04 with error message:

```
$BINARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by $BINARY)
```

How can I compile my binary so it runs on old Ubuntus and RHEL6, CentOS 6.4?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser!, you might be checking out [unix.se] the answer might be there

Comment: Why not just upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @Braiam hi there, it's not my choice, I am distributing the binary to the end users bundled with application. There is no way to force *all* users to upgrade their ubuntus :)